# Media Metadata Retriever scaled image

Tags: android, image, memory, bitmap, kotlin

Is there a better solution to get frame of a video?

Is there any issue with the scaling image part?

If I don't use the bitmaps (remove code) and run the same scenario (open view for 10 times) the Memory Usage that the Profiler shows is 30-40MB smaller than when I am using those bitmaps that I am getting from the `mediaMetadataRetriever`

```
private fun getScaledBitmap(timeUs: Long): Bitmap? {
    try {
        mediaMetadataRetriever?.getFrameAtTime(timeUs, MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST_SYNC)?.let {
            val result = Bitmap.createBitmap(frameWidth, frameHeight, it.config)
            val canvas = Canvas(result)
            val scaleX = frameWidth.toFloat() / it.width.toFloat()
            val scaleY = frameHeight.toFloat() / it.height.toFloat()
            val scale = if (scaleX > scaleY) scaleX else scaleY
            val w = (it.width * scale).toInt()
            val h = (it.height * scale).toInt()
            val srcRect = Rect(0, 0, it.width, it.height)
            val destRect = Rect((frameWidth - w) / 2, (frameHeight - h) / 2, w, h)
            canvas.drawBitmap(it, srcRect, destRect, null)
            it.recycle()
            return result
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    return null
}
```

> note `frameWidth` and `frameHeight` are the desired size of the frame

Comment: @pskink because the original is too big and I want just a scaled down version

Comment: @pskink because this call doesn't maintain the aspect ratio

Comment: @pskink even with the createScaledBitmap there are memory issues, let's not concentrate on how the scale works